# Static methods and perm gen space in java

Tags: java, heap-memory, permgen

I have read several articles about how we should not create unnecessary static methods and should use singleton pattern instead.

I also understand that static methods take up perm gen space(up until java 8) which is an expensive space in the heap.

My question is: java metadata (class definitions, etc) is also stored in perm gen; by making a method within a class static, am I taking up more space than the metadata itself? Is there something like 'static instance' which takes up more space than the class's metadata (if the method was not static)?

Comment: I believe that a problem like connection/memory leak is more probable

Comment: The language spec doesn't say anything about it, so it's technically implementation-specific -- but there's no reason for a static method and an instance method to take a different amount of memory. The typical approach is to have them all be the same thing, and have instance methods implicitly take `this` as a first argument (and otherwise act like static methods).

Comment: Also note that Java 1.8 got rid of the permgen space.

Comment: Yeah, I know java 8 replaces perm gen with metaspace.. pretty cool. But my question was more about the perm gen space itself. Given that Java stores metadata and immutable instances in permgen, will making a method static take more space in permgen(as compared to the class def for that class which is stored as metadata anyway)? The reason I ask this question is that if metadata is stored anyway in permgen, why is making methods static bad for permgen?

Comment: I have not heard that static methods have any implication for permgen - do you have any links to the articles? As far as I understand there are no permgen issues of using static methods.  Static variables can be more problematic with memory leaks/GC (as they are generally longer living), but not methods.